# What genre is the end credits song in *The Lost Vikings* (Super Nintendo)?

Tags: identify-this-genre

In the game [*The Lost Vikings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Vikings) released for [Super Nintendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Nintendo_Entertainment_System), there is a song at the end credits featuring a "rock concert" of the Vikings. [Here is a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IJqRfF1RL4) to the end credits song.

I really like this kind of music, can anyone tell me what genre this falls under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this game came out in 1992, which makes sense, because this is a dead-on low-bandwidth version of the then currently popular rock-influenced pop R&B and hip-hop styles.

Compare the beat and basslines of contemporary hits such as

- [Hip Hop Hooray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qA2_-eQ26tY) - Naughty By Nature 1993
- [Jump!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=010KyIQjkTk) - Kriss Kross 1992
- [Jump Around!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZaz7OqyTHQ) - House of Pain 1992
- [My Perogative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cDLZqe735k) - Bobby Brown 1988
- [Talk to Myself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyRZIbC_n-c)  - Christopher Williams 1989
- [Miss You Much](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vCjfpldsbE) - Janet Jackson 1989

The record scratches, the "kick it" intro and the quarter-note weak-beat shouts are all dead giveaways.  Also that 90's whole note, whole note, half note, half note, quarter-quarter-quarter-quarter turnaround (such as at 0:33).

Answer (score 0):

Midi. 
I think...
The sounds aren't very authentic because they are identical to the last ones played. But I'm not sure if midi counts for a genre.

Answer (score 0):

The genre is Chiptune.  SNES soundtracks are usually grouped in with Chiptune because while the generators are not simple wave forms, the samples and tracking are highly compressed due to technology limitations based on the soundchip.

Comment: This doesn't sound anything like typical Chiptune music to me.

Comment: Here's a random [Chiptune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMvo68V31nQ) mix I just found --it's based much more heavily on the distinctive [original NES sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5j1y_aZORZs).  By the time the SNES came along they could simulate real instruments much more believably (and therefore less distinctively).

Comment: It is still a chiptune.  The SNES and the Sega Genesis pretty much represent the end of the Chiptune era of videogame music. This is highly connected to the demoscene.

Comment: I guess I could see that classification if we were talking about new music made to sound like this.  But to me this is pretty clearly a direct imitation of the music that was on the radio at that same time. At least in my opinion, "Chiptune" is a modern genre that just sounds vintage.